# How to manage failover of Spark Streaming process with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using Spark's direct streaming API to get Spark streaming batches.  But since the direct streaming API does not synchronize offsets with Zookeeper, we loose the events that were received while spark streaming application was down.  I want to know what is the recommended approach to solve this problem.